# Why did this character's yells trigger the Mother Boxes?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

In the opening scene, Superman yells out in pain after being stabbed. The yells
then oscillate over very far distances, and reach the Mother Boxes at three locations:

1. Cyborg's house
2. Mera's underwater residence
3. Amazon Shrine.

Why did Superman's yells trigger the Mother Boxes?

Comment: His death cry triggered them. Mother boxes are sentient; they sensed that after Superman's death, there was no one [strong enough] to protect the planet .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained later in the movie, it's not so much his scream than his death that triggers the motherbox.

Circa 2h20

> Bruce :
> Victor's father activated a Mother Box more than a year ago
> when Superman was still alive. Didn't call out to Steppenwolf. None of
> the boxes did. Not until...
>
> Diana :
> Not until Superman died.
>
> Bruce:
> Not until Superman died.
>
> Barry:
> It's like they were afraid of him?
>
> Bruce:
> Yes, they were afraid of him.

My guess here is that the oscillation is the call to Steppenwolf.

I'm aware it's only a partial 'why', it doesn't fully explain how the motherbox were omniscient enough to understand this scream was a death scream, or at what level the motherboxes were sentient enough to be afraid of superman.

Comment: Regarding "why": The boxes have intergalactic communication: Steppenwolf says, "The one that woke and called to me" and at least planetary sense "... the third box [can be] ... only [be] sense[d] [by Box 1 & 2." On their competence Diana states, "Indestructible living machines made from a science so advanced it looks like sorcery . . . These boxes together are world destroyers. A billion years old. They'll get inside you..."  So basically "magic" of a sort.